# Rewriting a difference of two squares as a difference of two cubes

Tags: polynomials

Recently, I was asked about the equation $x^2-y^2=A(x,y)^3-B(x,y)^3$
where the unknowns $A$ and $B$ are rational fractions in ${\mathbb C}(x,y)$.

If $A$ and $B$ are polynomials, then $(x-y)(x+y)=(A-B)(A^2+AB+B^2)$,
so $A-B$ must be of the form $c$ or $c(x-y)$ or $c(x+y)$
where $c$ is a nonzero scalar. Now $A-B$ cannot be a nonzero constant because
$x^2-y^2$ has no constant term, so $A-B$
cannot be a constant. If $A-B=c(x-y)$, then
$x+y=c(B^2+(B+x-y)B+(B+x-y)^2)$, and putting $y=x$ we deduce $2x=B(x,x)^3$ which
is impossible. A similar contradiction is deduced from $A-B=c(x+y)$.

So there are no polynomial solutions. It is not clear to me however if there
are non-polynomial solutions.